# An example of function in $\textit{L} ^p([0,1])$ but not in $\textit{L} ^{\infty}([0,1])$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I would like to show that $\bigcap_{p\ge1}\textit{L}^p([0,1])\setminus \textit{L}^{\infty}([0,1])\not=\emptyset$, so does somebody know a function that is in this set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function in that set is $f(x)=\log(x)$.

$\forall p\ge 1$ there exists a neighborhood $U(0^+)$ s.t. $|f(x)|^p\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ in it, so
$$\int_{(0,1)}|\log(x)|^pdx\le \int_{U(0^+)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\int_{(0,1)\setminus U(0^+)}|\log(x)|^pdx < +\infty$$
and we can conclude that $f\in \textit{L}^p([0,1])$ for all $p\ge 1$.

This function is not in $\textit{L}^{\infty}([0,1])$, because it satisfies:
$$\forall M\in\mathbb{R} \mbox{ I have that }|\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>M\}|>0$$
in fact, given $M>0$ the set described above is the interval $(0,e^{-M})$ so it has positive measure.

Comment: In the second sentence of the answer, the inequality should read $|f(x)|^p\leq\frac1{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I'll edit right away